# How to access parent scopes recursively?

Tags: c++, scope

I tried to do a fancy macro to have some debug informations: The name of the scope you currently are! This can be picked up by e.g. an assert. I tried to made it recursive:

```
// Global namespace
struct ScopeDef{ static const char* GetName() {return "";} };
typedef ScopeDef ScopeDefParent;

// Macro to place into your namespace/scope
#define NG_SCOPEDEF(scopename) \
    struct ScopeDef { \
        static const char* GetName() {return scopename;} \
        typedef ScopeDefParent Parent; \
    }; \
    typedef ScopeDef ScopeDefParent;
```

And using it like:

```
// Recursive template for testing
template< class T > void PrintImpl() {
    PrintImpl< T::Parent >();
    printf("::%s", T::GetName() );
}
template<> void PrintImpl< ::ScopeDef >() {}
template< class T > void PrintS() { PrintImpl<T>(); printf("\n");}

// Lets try it:
namespace First {
    NG_SCOPEDEF( "First" );
    namespace Second {
        NG_SCOPEDEF( "Second" );
        static void AFun() {
            // This prints "::First::Second"
            PrintS<ScopeDef>();
        }
    }
    struct Third {
        NG_SCOPEDEF( "Third" );
        static void BFun() {
            // This is endless recursion
            PrintS<ScopeDef>();
        }
    };
}
```

It doesn't work in class scopes, because the order of definitions don't matter.

This is not a good solution. So is there a way to access the parent scope in a way? In regular code I would just qualify ("::First::ScopeDef"), but that's nothing for a macro.

Comment: do you have a good reason not to use __FILE__ and __LINE__ which roughly speaking give the same information?

Comment: They are helpful, yes, but not the same. Most things in my mind would use the struct like the template PrintS<> above.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this in C++, where you put in the macro whenever you open a scope and let the destructor take care of cleanup when the scope exits.  This example will print out the full scope to stderr, and the output of this code is as follows.

```
main
main::First
main::First::Second
main::First::Second::DummyClass::DummyFunction
main::First
main
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class NG_SCOPE_CLASS;

NG_SCOPE_CLASS* NG_SCOPE_END = 0;

class NG_SCOPE_CLASS
{
public: 
    NG_SCOPE_CLASS(const char* scope)
    {
        _scope = scope;
        _prev = NG_SCOPE_END;
        NG_SCOPE_END = this;
    }
    ~ NG_SCOPE_CLASS()
    {
        NG_SCOPE_END = _prev;
    }
    void PrintScope()
    {
        if(_prev)
        {
            _prev->PrintScope();
            fprintf(stderr, "::");
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", _scope);
    }
private:
    NG_SCOPE_CLASS* _prev;
    const char* _scope;
};

#define NG_SCOPE_PRINT { if(NG_SCOPE_END) { NG_SCOPE_END->PrintScope(); fprintf(stderr, "\n"); } }
#define NG_SCOPE(X) NG_SCOPE_CLASS _NG_SCOPE_CLASS(X)

// THAT'S IT FOR THE DEFINITIONS ABOVE, BELOW IS JUST SOME SAMPLE CODE.

class DummyClass
{
public:
    void DummyFunction()
    {
        NG_SCOPE("DummyClass::DummyFunction");
        NG_SCOPE_PRINT;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    NG_SCOPE("main");
    NG_SCOPE_PRINT;
    {
        NG_SCOPE("First");
        NG_SCOPE_PRINT;
        {
            NG_SCOPE("Second");
            NG_SCOPE_PRINT;
            DummyClass theDummyInstance;
            theDummyInstance.DummyFunction();
        }
        NG_SCOPE_PRINT;
    }
    NG_SCOPE_PRINT;
}
```

Comment: +1 not a bad idea. Looks sort of like what the boost log libs use. Seems like you don't really need macros though and can do it just with functions?

Comment: The basic idea is that destructors for things on the stack are intrinsically associated with the scope, so if you can get a local variable into every scope, the rest is done for you correctly by C++.  (Don't put two such variables in the same scope though!)  So you can't do it with *just* functions, you need the object on the stack.  Whether you accomplish that with macros or not, is up to you, this is just an example.

Comment: This approach is using one global variable (not threadsafe) and relays on the construction of objects, which is not possible for giving the namespace a name or the class scope, like I tried.

Another thing is that your DummyFunction is now below "main::First::Second::" which was not intended by me. Well, not always at least, I agree it is nice to appear in the scope of the caller.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, our working solution:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
    // GCC solution below. Note MSVC gives warning about unused typedefs but can be suppressed.
    #define NG_SCOPEDEF(scopename) \
        struct ScopeDefTag { static const char* Name(){return (scopename);}; }; \
        typedef ::Scopes::Impl< ScopeDefTag, ScopeDef > ScopeDefHelper; \
        struct ScopeDef : ScopeDefHelper {}
#else
    // GCC seems to not look ahead.
    #define NG_SCOPEDEF(scopename) \
        struct ScopeDefTag { static const char* Name(){return (scopename);}; struct SDH : ::Scopes::Impl< ScopeDefTag, ScopeDef >{}; }; \
        struct ScopeDef : ScopeDefTag::SDH {}
#endif

namespace Scopes {
struct Chain {
    const char* const   m_Lit;
    const Chain* const  m_Prev;
    Chain(const char* lit, const Chain* prev) :m_Lit(lit), m_Prev(prev) {}
};

template< bool DMY = true >
struct RootScopeDef
{
    static const Chain chain;
    static const Chain* Get() { return &chain; }
};
// Being template just to have this in header:
template< bool DMY > const Chain RootScopeDef<DMY>::chain = Chain( "", 0 );


template< class TAG, class PARENT >
struct Impl {
    static const Chain chain;
    static const Chain* Get() { return &chain; }
    typedef PARENT Parent;
};

template< class TAG, class PARENT >
const Chain Impl<TAG, PARENT>::chain = Chain( TAG::Name(), &PARENT::chain );

} // namespace

// Global namespace
typedef Scopes::RootScopeDef<> ScopeDef;
```

It is based on loopholes in the compiler and is not standard compliant! MSVS thinks that the ScopeDef used as template argument isn't the following one, since it is depending on that very typedef, so it resolves to the parent one, which will be shadowed after. This also works when the macro is placed in a template, because MSVS instantiates them lazily. GCC instead seems to just not look ahead and resolves the base of SDH to the correct one. MSVS would produce an infinite loop of m_Prev references here.

Bottom line: this gives you a nice way to print out namespaces and classes for debugging purposes, but also serves as types for e.g. specializations of templates!